# Yii2 custom errorHandler component

Tags: php, error-handling, yii2

I need override some functions of `yii\web\ErrorHandler` and create child class `api\components\ErrorHandler`.

Config app in `api/config/main.php`:

```
`...
 'errorHandler' => [
   'class' => \api\components\ErrorHandler::class,
 ],
 ...`
```

Error in *nginx* log:

`FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class api\components\ApiErrorHandler does not exist' in path/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:415`

Comment: Obviously somewhere in your code there is this call for `ApiErrorHandler` that does not exist in pointed namespace. Find it and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using `yii/app-advanced`, you need to let yii know where namespace roots are.
add the following line to `common/config/bootstrap`

```
Yii::setAlias('@api', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api'); // add api alias
```

otherwise carefully check your folder structure, file and class names